# many to many attach() says trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

I have two database tables `journeys` and `stops` that are related in a many-to-many relationship. There is also the third table `journey_stop` (the pivot table) for the relationship.

### Models

Here is my `Journey.php` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Journey extends Model
{

    public function stops() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Stop');
    }
}
```

and the `Stop.php` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Stop extends Model
{
    public function journeys(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Journey');
    }

}
```

### Controller

Now in my controller, I have written a method `changeStop(stop, journey_id)` which takes a particular `journey_id` and either assigns a stop to it.(that is, creates a relationship between that particular `stop` and the `journey`) or removes the `stop` from the `journey` if it already exists.

Here is the method:

```
public function changeStop(Request $request, $id)
{
    $stop = $request->all();
    $journey = Journey::find($id);

    if ($journey->stops()->contains($stop->id)) {
        $journey->stops()->detach($stop->id);
    }else{
        $journey->stops()->attach($stop->id);
    }  


    return $journey->stops();
}
```

But the line with the `if` statement throws the error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

I have also tried using `DB` to query the pivot table directly but it throws the same error. Here's the code with `DB`:

```
public function changeStop(Request $request, $id)
{
    $stop = $request->all();
    $journey = Journey::find($id);

    if (
        DB::table('journey_stop')->where(
            'journey_id',
            $id
        )->where(
            'stop_id',
            $stop->id
        )->count() > 0
    ) {
        $journey->stops->detach($stop->id);
    } else {
        $journey->stops->attach($stop->id);
    }

    return $journey->stops();
}
```

Everything seems right for me. But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also use the [`sync`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method to construct many-to-many associations. The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the intermediate table

```
$journey->stops()->sync([$stop_id])
```

And to work for your above code try this:

```
public function changeStop(Request $request, $id)
{
    $stop = $request->all(); // returns an array
    $journey = Journey::find($id);

    if ($journey->stops->contains('id', $stop['id'])) {
            $journey->stops()->detach($stop['id']);
    } else {
        $journey->stops()->attach($stop['id']);
    }

    return $journey->stops;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked! You really made my day. I've been banging my head on this for over hours.